# Generate Half-Sorted BubbleSort

Tags: c++, sorting

I was trying to generate partial-sorted array.

There are many ways to do & i chosen my own method which is to use any of the sorting algorithm out there, there put a "break" in the middle of the sorting.

In this case,i choose Bubble sort.

What I did was, i stop the sorting of the value when is the counter has reached half of n values

But, I have no idea how it isn't working based on my logic.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    int i, j, p,n,temp;
    cout << "Enter No. of Elements : ";
    cin >> n;//user desired of total integers
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)//this will loop from 1 to n value
    {
        a.push_back(i);//push into a vector
    }


    for (p = 1; p <= n ; p++)             
    {

        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (j<n/2)// this is where, the sorting will stop
            {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[j];                      // Interchange Values
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    cout << "\nAfter Sorting : \n";
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you first build a sorted array ?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Are you trying to sort only the first half of the array and leave the other half unchanged? Cause if that's the case it's just a matter of replacing n with n/2 in your sort loops ...

Comment: but i did put my a statement to stop sorting in the middle

Comment: @dragosht, this is wad i did earlier..but din work

for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (j<n/2)// this is where, the sorting will stop
            {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[j];                      // Interchange Values
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @quantdev , sorry i just noticed about that... Because before I try to create & push value into a vector using that for loop...i enter manually .

Comment: @BetaTracks my answer still applies :)

Comment: You also didn't use Bubblesort. Bubblesort only compares *adjacent* elements *and* swap detection to terminate the algorithm if there is ever a sequence pass (even the initial pass) that produces no swaps. It is the latter that gives bubblesort a best-case complexity of O(N), something your posted algorithm does *not* have.

Answer (score 0):

You array is initially sorted, at least generate it in reversed order to make your tests meaningful (or you could use some random generators, too) :

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Then, your logic is flawed: you can't stop a bubble sort half the way (a bubble sort does not guarantee you that the previously moved elements won't be moved again, that's why it needs N^2 iterations), instead, you need to make it iterates over `n/2` elements instead of `n`.

Something like :

```
for (p = 0; p <= n / 2; p++)             
{
    for (j = 0; j <= n / 2; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
        {
            temp = a[j];                      
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
            a[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```